# a function f on R whose inverse image is measurable, BUT f is not measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

Can some one give an example of a function f on R such that the inverse image on all t belongs to R is measurable, BUT f is not measurable.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be an unmeasurable set, a Vitali set. Then $\chi_S,$ the indicator function on $S$, is not a measurable function. Yet, $\chi_S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})=\{0,1\}$ which is measurable.

Comment: Thank You so much.   Regards

Comment: @ShumailaJaved if it has answered your question satisfactorily, please click the check mark to accept the answer.